# How to stop a scrollbar from scrolling down as you add items to it's canvas

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I've written a class for a Scrollable Frame, which looks like this:

```
class ScrollFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, size, look={}, canvas_look={}):
        args = dict(relief=tk.GROOVE, bd=1,bg='white')
        args.update(look)
        canvas_args = dict(bg='light grey')
        canvas_args.update(canvas_look)
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **args)
        self.wide = size[0]
        self.high = size[1]
        
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, **canvas_args)
        self.canvas.pack(side='left')
        
        self.inner = tk.Frame(self.canvas,width=self.wide)
        self.inner.bind("<Configure>",self.scrollfunction)
        
        self.canvas.create_window((0,0),window=self.inner,width=self.wide)
        
        self.scroll= tk.Scrollbar(self,orient='vertical',command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)
        self.scroll.pack(side='right',fill='y')
        
    def scrollfunction(self,event):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all'),width=self.wide,height=self.high)
```

Essentially, I have a frame within a canvas (called self.inner) which can be used to add other widgets to. The canvas itself is scrollable, thus creating a frame that can be scrolled over. The functionality of this frame is exactly as I want it to be. However, I've found that when I add items to the frame as in the example below, the scrollbar will scroll down as items are added. I want the scrollbar and window to stay at the top, but it won't.

```
root = tk.Tk()

def create_page(root):
    scrollframe = ScrollFrame(root, size=[300,300])

    labels=[]
    for i in range(0,100):
        labels.append(tk.Label(scrollframe.inner,text='Label number '+str(i)))
        labels[i].grid(row=i,column=0)
```

I tried adding the line `scrollframe.canvas.yview_moveto('0.0')` to the create_page function which should reset the position of the scrollbar. When I call this with a button (`btn = tk.Button(root,text='Reset',command=scrollframe.canvas.yview_moveto('0.0'))` then click it once the page is loaded) it works fine. It won't call itself if I just put the line at the end of the create_page function though.

So I don't know where to go now. I can't get the create_page function to add all the items to the scrollframe then reset the scrollbar to the top once it's done. It seems to require external input to call this command... Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You may need to add `anchor="nw"` in `self.canvas.create_window(...)`.

Comment: You know what, it's often the simple things that are overlooked... Thanks for the help! 
Still not sure why my attempted fix with yview_moveto didn't work, but at least something works!

Comment: It is because without the `anchor="nw"` the bounding box returned by `self.canvas.bbox("all")` will be something like `(-x1, -y1, +x2, +y2)`.  So `(0, 0)` is not at the top-left of the scroll region.

Comment: Aah that makes more sense now. I didn't realise the bbox was set up like that. Do you want to post your solution as an answer and I can accept it as a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not specify `anchor` option in `self.canvas.create_window(...)`, it will be center by default.  Therefore the bounding box returned by `self.canvas.bbox("all")` will be something like `(-x1, -y1, +x2, +y2)` and so `(0, 0)` is not at the top-left of the scroll region.

Add `anchor="nw"` to `.create_window(...)` and then the bounding box returned by `.bbox("all")` will be something like `(0, 0, +x, +y)`.